# MasterDetail - Menu icon not showing inside NavigationPage

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm developing an app that has a Login ContentPage and, after the user logs in, I'm trying to show a MasterDetail page. My Menu needs to be positioned below the action bar. So, to accomplish that, I put my MasterDetailPage inside a NavigationPage.

But problem is, after the user clicks on a button at Login Page, the Menu Icon doesn't appear at the action bar. If I render the MasterDetailPage without the loginPage, the menu works just fine.

**MasterDetailPage (the master layout is inside RootPage.xaml)**

```
public partial class RootPage : MasterDetailPage
{
    public RootPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Detail = new Feed();
    }
}
```

**This works perfectly**

```
public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new RootPage());
    }
```

**This doesn't show the menu icon**

```
public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Login());
    }
```

*User clicks at a button*

```
 private void Login_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new RootPage());
}
```

[Github sample](https://github.com/guilhermeikeda/MasterDetailSample)

Comment: i'm having the same problem

Comment: @HeeroYuy - Did you get the resolution for this? I ran the app and found out some details which will help you people